# TypeScript says return type of function is either `A | B`, but by passing arguments it must be A since check happens inside

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have implemented `client` function that accepts an optional `formatter` parameter which is either `function` or `undefined`, even though I'm checking if the `formatter` is `undefined` or not, and return the result based on that inside `client`, but TS seems to ignore the check and show the return value wrong. What am I missing in here?

Function implementation:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { Required } from "utility-types";
import { AxiosRequestConfig } from "axios";

const client = async <D, F>(
    { url, ...config }: Required<AxiosRequestConfig, "url">,
    formatter?: (data: D) => F
) => {
    const response = await axios.request<D>({
        url: encodeURI(url),
        ...config,
    });
    if (typeof formatter === "undefined") {
        return response;
    }
    return formatter(response.data);
};
```

Usage:

```
const formatHomeData = (data: HomePageResponse) => {
    return {
        products: data.result.bestSell, // This will result in an Array
        slides: data.result.sliders,
        notification: data.result.alert,
    };
};

export const fetchIndex = async () => {
    const url = 'http://localhost:4000/home';
    const formatted = await client({ url }, formatHomeData);
    const products = formatted.products; // TS complains here
};

fetchIndex();
```

TS Error

```
Property 'products' does not exist on type '{ products: FormattedProduct[]; slides: SliderItemResponse[]; notification: string; } | AxiosResponse<HomePageResponse>'.
Property 'products' does not exist on type 'AxiosResponse<HomePageResponse>'.ts(2339)
```

By the way, I'm using Generics, so that I don't have to keep defining the return type of `formatter` functions explicitly each time like this:

```
interface FormatHomeDataReturnType {
    products: FormattedProduct[];
    slides: SliderItemResponse[];
    notification: string;
}
```

Here's a link to [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAQwB7AgZzgMyhEcBEyqa+A3AFCiSxwDecASgKYCOArsFEwCZwC+WHHnxsYwADbAYATwC0MsExIUq0ePQCCKdM3ZKYAYQgA7TMADm-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-Fg-puCyVD0OdUhw0jKMAzgFxwHEE5djgGMBiYSdHEwRdl1XJB4lFShvAGTAECcfZ4J1PUDX5XcUk1NA0F1JhijcKAM3Mb8UzTYobWBPJhSdYp6k0mARKNJSixLAYywDYyoB+foQH03YmAAbQAXUMlJ-TcIMQ2KLNpEc5zkiHEdZJgeTjEUqEKBZDNuV4-i4B0vi9PpI0xL87huC2PYyzkhSlLAO9iUyoKFJ8h4mB6CRAuC0Ki2vYAh1Mmq6psxkxS4qK+P2AMGvENAmv2NSMzcXU8xACrsoeGBEyxKBRpCpToqYX0IAgABrGaqpSQ4Y16KSwHPOAstmlrIp49q4DMusBks0reuSuA62KYw2BAf0oCU0BpLWpSxBgYdPoeUsnHksAxBMP69y4XoeAAfV6B6vXEJS2DAIVodhlt4fCoA) in the minimalist way I could make it.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mZb4am) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.  Any code not necessary to demonstrate the issue should be removed.

Comment: @jcalz thank you for your time making that, I updated my question to include it and fixed those undefined interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be really nice if Typescript could infer this automatically, but it's not so automatic. It does give you a way to specify it explicitly using [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) though.

Overloads are a way to define the return type for different variations of a function signature. For a generic async lambda like in your example, this looks like:

```js
type ClientOverload = {
  <D, F>(urlAndConfig: Required<AxiosRequestConfig, 'url'>): Promise<AxiosResponse<D>>;
  <D, F>(urlAndConfig: Required<AxiosRequestConfig, 'url'>, formatter: (data: D) => F): Promise<F>;
};
const client: ClientOverload = async <D, F>(...) { ... };
```

If you add the overload explicitly stating how defining `formatting` affects the return type, you won't get an error trying to use the `products` property.